# Method accepting either a file buffer or a string

Tags: string, io, rust

I am writing a method which would parse content of a file. For testing purposes, I would like to pass a `&str` to this method.

I was not able to find a way to do this, but there probably is some trait which does this. Maybe a different approach is required?

So far I have this:

```
fn read_buff<R: Read>(buffer: BufReader<R>) {}
```

This fails to compile:

```
let s = "str";
let mut reader = BufReader::new(s); // fails to compile.
read_buff(reader);
```

It would be best if I had access to the methods provided by the `BufReader` such as `read_line`.

Comment: The two snippets you've provided aren't really related in any way. Can you provide an [mcve] for us?

Comment: The only specific addition for this question to the linked duplicate is [`str::as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead not really sure how snippets were unrelated, I just wanted to show that  you can not create BufReader from &str.  Anyway, thanks to Shepmaster, invoking the 'as_bytes()' does the trick.

Comment: @AleksanderFular I was confused given your `read_buff` example, but the example failing to compile didn't use `read_buff` at all. Glad you have your answer though.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yep, I guess I was missing the invocation to the read_buff method :). Edited.